# Manual authentication for Google API in jclouds, separating token acquisition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jclouds, google-compute-engine

I need to separate the authentication phase from Google's Api creation, but it's very difficult (for me) to make it possible.

This is very important because I am creating a REST API that should receive the authorization tokens previously acquired and not the credentials directly from its users for security reasons, because with tokens I can set a lifetime limit as specified in [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

I have the following code:

```java
public class Main { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
      
        // Reads the JSON credential file provided by Google
        String jsonContent = readJson(args[1]);  
        
        // Pass the credential content
        GoogleComputeEngineApi googleApi = 
                createApi(jsonContent); 
    }
    
    public static GoogleComputeEngineApi createApi(final String jsonCredentialContent) {
        try {
            Supplier<Credentials> credentialSupplier = new GoogleCredentialsFromJson(
                    jsonCredentialContent);

            ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder
                    .newBuilder("google-compute-engine")
                    .credentialsSupplier(credentialSupplier)
                    .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);

            Credentials credentials = credentialSupplier.get();
            ContextBuilder contextBuilder = ContextBuilder
                    .newBuilder(GoogleComputeEngineProviderMetadata.builder()
                            .build())
                    .credentials(credentials.identity, credentials.credential);

            Injector injector = contextBuilder.buildInjector();
            return injector.getInstance(GoogleComputeEngineApi.class);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }  
}
```

Below is a fake code with my needs:

```java
public class Main { 
            
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        
        String jsonCredentialContent = readJson(args[1]);  
        String oauthToken = "";
        
        // First acquires the OAuth token
        if(getAuthenticationType("google-compute-engine").equals("oauth")) {
            oauthToken = getTokenForOAuth(jsonCredentialContent);
        }        
                    
        // Creates the Api with the previously acquired token
        GoogleComputeEngineApi googleApi = 
                createApi(oauthToken); 
    }       
    
    [...]
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use the jclouds OAuth API to get the bearer token, as follows:

```java
GoogleCredentialsFromJson credentials = new GoogleCredentialsFromJson(jsoncreds);

AuthorizationApi oauth = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("google-compute-engine")
    .credentialsSupplier(credentials)
    .buildApi(AuthorizationApi.class);

try {
    long nowInSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    Claims claims = Claims.create(
        credentials.get().identity, // issuer
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute", // write scope
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", // audience
        nowInSeconds + 60, // token expiration (seconds)
        nowInSeconds // current time (secods)
    );
    Token token = oauth.authorize(claims);
    System.out.println(token);
} finally {
    oauth.close();
}
```

Once you have the Bearer access token you can create the jclouds context with it as follows:

```java
// Override GCE default Oauth flow (JWT) by the Bearer token flow
Properties overrides = new Properties();
overrides.put(OAuthProperties.CREDENTIAL_TYPE, CredentialType.BEARER_TOKEN_CREDENTIALS.toString());

// It is important to set the proper identity too, as it is used to resolve the GCE project
ComputeServiceContext ctx = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("google-compute-engine")
    .overrides(overrides)
    .credentials(credentials.get().identity, token.accessToken())
    .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);

GoogleComputeEngineApi google = ctx.unwrapApi(GoogleComputeEngineApi.class);
```

Comment: It worked! Could you tell me also how I could get the token using the same jclouds library? I am also trying to implement but with some difficulty.

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a complete example.

Comment: Ignasi, at the moment I'm doing the same job for AWS, could you tell me if you have any test code that does the same thing you posted above only for Amazon? I've looked a lot here in the JClouds code and I do not find anything on Google either.